# How do I calculate and return a value using a JavaScript object method

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

I have created this object:

```
var resultStats = {
    possibleResults: 10,
    validResults: 5,
};
```

What would I write so that writing`resultsStats["calculateSuccessRate()"]` (or similar) will calculate `Math.round(100*this.validResults/this.possibleResults);` and return the answer of 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var resultStats = {
    possibleResults: 10.0,
    validResults: 5.0,
    calculateSuccessRate: function(){
        return Math.round(100 * this.validResults/this.possibleResults);
    }
};
```

The function could then be called using:

```
resultStats["calculateSuccessRate"]();
```

Or:

```
resultStats.calculateSuccessRate();
```

Comment: (N.B. If you don't need to access the property dynamically, the bottom method is preferred.)

Comment: Thanks! But why is the bottom method preferred?

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultStats = {
    calculateSuccessRate : function() {
       return Math.round(100 * (this.possibleResults / this.validResults))
    },
    possibleResults: 10,
    validResults: 5
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could a `calculateSuccessRate` function to the `resultStats` object.

```
var resultsStats = {
    possibleResults: 10,
    validResults: 5,
    calculateSuccessRate: function(){
        return Math.round(100*this.validResults/this.possibleResults);
    }
};
```

Then you can call it like:

```
resultsStats.calculateSuccessRate();
```

OR (you were close):

```
resultsStats["calculateSuccessRate"]()
```